# In modal form get element value correct row

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have problem with getting info in my modal form. I have rows what shows information. Screen shot bellow
[image]

Then i press button right im getting modal window. Screen shot bellow
[image]

I want make then i press my button in right get what row info and put in input.

My code in php and html

```
            <div>
                    <table>
                        <?php
                            
                        $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM education WHERE education_id='".$info['nick_id']."' ORDER BY start_date");
                        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                        
                            ?>
                
                            <tr>    
                                    
                           <b><?=$row['name']?></b><br> 
                           <?=$row['specelybe']?> <span style="float:right;"> <button type="button" class="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"> <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"  style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true"></i>   </button> </span> <br>
                             <?=$row['start_date']?> -    <?=$row['end_date']?> <br>
                    
                         </tr> 
                            <?php
                    
                            
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
    
        </div>
```

MY MODAL FORM code

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Išsilavinimo redagavimas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" name="nameuni" placeholder="NAME of uni"   required>
    <br>
               <input type="text" name="namestudc" placeholder="NAME of program"   required>
    <br>


               <input type="date" name="startdate" placeholder="START DATE" id="startdate" required>
    <br>

               <input type="date" name="endDate" placeholder="END DATE" id="endDate" required>         


       </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My js code

```
<script>
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
     
})
</script>
```

I try make table then select like row something like what

```
 var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
```

But its now work for me. Maybe u have some solution?
All help will be appreciated

Comment: Please show the html code of table, and the whole function for click event.

Comment: look php code, and you see row function and in the right you can see ```<span style="float:right;"> <button type="button" class="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"> <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"  style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true"></i>   </button> </span>``` Now in code ist table but i can try make it fast.

Comment: what you want??

Comment: I WANT GET INFO IN MODAL WINDOW SAME ROW AS I PRESS BUTTON.

Comment: Fix your HTML first of all. You say you are creating a table, but it hardly is one - you follow `<tr>` with a `<div>` instead of a `<th>` or a `<td>`, and then that div element doesn’t even get closed again properly anywhere.

Comment: If you want to read several different pieces of information from the DOM, then you should put them into the DOM in a halfway sensibly structured form in the first place. Right now, you have the name inside a `b` element, and the start and end date are not wrapped into an element of their own each at all - that will make reading those as individual values much harder. Create a proper HTML structure to hold this information first of all.

Comment: @CBroe i put my what do you mean name inside a b element? Like you see its while cycle, row have all table info, from select query, imposiible get what data in model form??? About ```<th>``` and ```<td>``` it look very bad if u use it so im using ```<tr>```. Im edit a bit my code bellow, div now before ```<table>```.

Comment: Your English is _really_ hard to understand here. _What_ information do you want to “send” to your modal via that button click? I assumed name of uni, name of program and those two dates, is what you want to have shown inside the modal? So you would need to have access to those four values separately, which with what you are currently creating as output inside your table row will be rather hard to get, because in there, these pieces of information are _not_structured in a way, that JS could easily access them each individually.

Comment: _“About <th> and <td> it look very bad if u use it so im using <tr>”_ - that is an absolutely pointless argument. You _need_ at least one table cell inside a table row - otherwise the whole thing isn’t actually a table to begin with. And accessing the right elements via JavaScript will get harder, when you can not even be sure what DOM structure the browser will actually create, when it has to apply _error correction_ while parsing your HTML, because it has a nonsense structure to begin with.

Comment: Sorry for my English skills to explain situation. So you wanna say its hard to get element individually? but its a array. Yes im using like row ```$row['name']``` because i want to show name, and data too.  But really impossible get what array data in modal form? Or maybe u have some example how to make looking like this, in the another way how to put and get this info? Please give example if u can

Comment: With td looks like this. https://ibb.co/g9B3wkP . Okey its not currect table, maybe possible get with js info not from table but from row?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first off all don't need change table structure to do it. So first of all i change button to `<a>`

```
<table>
                        <?php
                            $delLinijos = 0;
                        $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM education WHERE education_id='".$info['nick_id']."' ORDER BY start_date");
                        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                    
                            ?>
                
                            <tr>    
        
                           <b><?=$row['name']?></b><br> 
                           <?=$row['specelybe']?> <span style="float:right;"> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#educationModal<?=$row['id']?>" > <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"  style="color:black;" aria-hidden="true"></i>   </a></span> <br>
                             <?=$row['start_date']?> -    <?=$row['end_date']?> <br>
                    </td>
                         </tr> 
                            <?php
                    
                        
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

Important place is `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#educationModal<?=$row['id']?>" >` for this stuff i can send row id to my modal form window.
so modal form in html looks like this.

query("SELECT * FROM education WHERE education_id='".$info['nick_id']."' ORDER BY start_date");
                            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

```
<div class="modal fade" id="educationModal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="educationModalLabel<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                   
             <hr class="style17">   
             
            
           <input type="text" name="namestudc" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" id="name" required>

            <br>
            
           <input type="text" name="specelybe" value="<?php echo $row['specelybe']; ?>" id="specelybe" required>

            <br>
            

           <input type="date" name="startdate" value="<?php echo $row['start_date']; ?>"  id="startdate" required>
            <br>
            

           <input type="date" name="endDate" value="<?php echo $row['end_date']; ?>"  id="endDate" required>           



             
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Uždaryti</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Išsaugoti</button>
                
                
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```